# Conflict between tkz-fct and thmtools?

Tags: thmtools, kvoptions, tkz-fct

I'm using TeXLive 2014. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}         % Must appear before {thmtools}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit  % No need to even plot anything!
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{theorem}[A Silly Theorem]
    Let $a = 1$. Then $a > 0$.
  \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
! Extra \endcsname.
\kv@processor@default ...fincsname\@xa \endcsname
                                                  \csname iftrue\endcsname \...
l.12   \begin{theorem}[A Silly Theorem]
```

If the optional theorem name is removed, all is well. Adding `\protect{}` doesn't help.

Any idea how to remove this conflict?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both packages use `\@xa` with ***very*** different meanings. For the Tkz suite, `\@xa` stands for a coordinate, while `thmtools` wants it to mean `\expandafter`.

In my opinion both are wrong in their assumption: Tkz should use a private name with a prefix, while `thmtools` should use `\@xp` like `amsmath` or have a prefix itself.

By changing all appearances of `\@xa` in the Tkz suite with a different name you should be able to get around the problem. The `\@xa` token appears only in `tkz-tools-base.tex` and `tkz-fct.sty`; I also changed the similarly named tokens, for uniformity.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}         % Must appear before {thmtools}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem{theorem}

\makeatletter
%%% patch tkz-tools-base.tex
\let\tkz@g@xa\tkz@init@xmin % don't undef \@xa or thmtools will be upset
\let\tkz@g@xb\tkz@init@xmax\undef\@xb
\let\tkz@g@ya\tkz@init@ymin\undef\@ya
\let\tkz@g@yb\tkz@init@ymax\undef\@yb
\patchcmd{\tkz@Init}
 {\global\let\@xa\tkz@init@xmin
  \global\let\@xb\tkz@init@xmax
  \global\let\@ya\tkz@init@ymin
  \global\let\@yb\tkz@init@ymax}
 {\global\let\tkz@g@xa\tkz@init@xmin
  \global\let\tkz@g@xb\tkz@init@xmax
  \global\let\tkz@g@ya\tkz@init@ymin
  \global\let\tkz@g@yb\tkz@init@ymax}
 {}{}
\patchcmd{\tkz@Grid}
 {(\@xa,\@ya)(\@xb,\@yb)}
 {(\tkz@g@xa,\tkz@g@ya)(\tkz@g@xb,\tkz@g@yb)}
 {}{}
%%% patch tkz-fct.sty
\patchcmd{\tkz@fct}
  {\@xa:\@xb}
  {\tkz@g@xa:\tkz@g@xb}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit  % No need to even plot anything!
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{theorem}[A Silly Theorem]
    Let $a = 1$. Then $a > 0$.
  \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Probably the issue should be made known to the maintainers of the Tkz suite and of `thmtools`.

Comment: Many thanks! That black magic does the trick beautifully.

Comment: The package has been updated since the bug report.